# Can you output text when the commit passes in SVN?

Tags: c#, svn, pre-commit-hook

We are using SVN and I would like to check the commit message for an string and give a warning that commits without this string will be bounced starting next month but currently allow the commit through.

stderr is only outputted when the commit fails, how do I allow the commit to succeed but still provide output to the user (I am writing the hook in C#)?

Comment: I have a solution that works if the hook is written as a windows batch script.  Let me know if you want the batch script solution.

Comment: It would be better than nothing, thanks!

Comment: @David, sorry for some reason my tag did not work in the previous comment and now I cannot edit it :-/

Answer (score 1):

Per your response above, here is the windows batch solution.

In the post-commit hook

```
:: repos = full path to physical repository
:: rev = the revision number related to the transaction committed
:: reposname = the name of the repository
set repos=%1
set rev=%2
set reposname=%~nx1
set Unwanted_String=string value

:: Capture commit message
svnlook log %repos% -r %rev%>%reposname%_%rev%_commit_statement.txt

:: Verify commit message meets requirements
powershell -command "If (Get-Content '%reposname%_%rev%_commit_statement.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '%Unwanted_String%'}) {'Found'} else {'Not found'}">%reposname%_%rev%_Is_String_Present.txt

:: Determine if feedback is needed
set /p Commit_Search=<%reposname%_%rev%_Is_String_Present.txt
if "%Commit_Search%"=="Found" (
echo ----------------------------------------------------->&2
echo The string %Unwanted_String% is not allowed >&2
echo In the future, please do not include this as part of your commit statement >&2
echo. >&2
echo Your change has been committed>&2
echo ----------------------------------------------------->&2
del *%reposname%_%rev%*.txt
exit /b 1
)
```

The output back to the user will show the object was committed along with an error message

> post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
>
> ---
>
> The string xxxxxx is not allowed
>
> In the future, please do not include this as part of your commit statement
>
> Your change has been committed
>
> ---

Once the grace period is over and you want to reject commit statements that contain this string, move the above lines to your pre-commit hook with one change

```
:: Capture commit message (-t is transaction in progress)
svnlook log -t %rev% %repos%>%reposname%_%rev%_commit_Statement.txt
```

Moving this to the pre-commit hook will prevent the commit and inform the user as to why it was rejected.